# Hadoop pseudo-distributed mode error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I have set-up Hadoop on a OpenSuse 11.2 VM using Virtualbox.I have made the prerequisite configs. I ran this example in the Standalone mode successfully. 
But in psuedo-distributed mode I get the following error:

---

```
$./bin/hadoop fs -put conf input
10/04/13 15:56:25 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream java.net.SocketException: Protocol not available                                                              
10/04/13 15:56:25 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Abandoning block blk_-8490915989783733314_1003        
10/04/13 15:56:31 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream java.net.SocketException: Protocol not available                                                              
10/04/13 15:56:31 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Abandoning block blk_-1740343312313498323_1003        
10/04/13 15:56:37 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream java.net.SocketException: Protocol not available                                                              
10/04/13 15:56:37 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Abandoning block blk_-3566235190507929459_1003        
10/04/13 15:56:43 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream java.net.SocketException: Protocol not available                                                              
10/04/13 15:56:43 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Abandoning block blk_-1746222418910980888_1003        
10/04/13 15:56:49 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: java.io.IOException: Unable to create new block.                                                                           
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:2845)                                                                                    
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2000(DFSClient.java:2102) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2288)                                                                                         

10/04/13 15:56:49 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block blk_-1746222418910980888_1003 bad datanode[0] nodes == null                                                               
10/04/13 15:56:49 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/max/input/core-site.xml" - Aborting...                                                           
put: Protocol not available                                                                  
10/04/13 15:56:49 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Exception closing file /user/max/input/core-site.xml : java.net.SocketException: Protocol not available
java.net.SocketException: Protocol not available
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.getIntOption0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.getIntOption(Net.java:178)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl$1.getInt(SocketChannelImpl.java:419)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketOptsImpl.getInt(SocketOptsImpl.java:60)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketOptsImpl.sendBufferSize(SocketOptsImpl.java:156)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketOptsImpl$IP$TCP.sendBufferSize(SocketOptsImpl.java:286)
        at sun.nio.ch.OptionAdaptor.getSendBufferSize(OptionAdaptor.java:129)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.getSendBufferSize(SocketAdaptor.java:328)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.createBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:2873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:2826)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2000(DFSClient.java:2102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2288)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are no live data nodes in the cluster. Did you check whether status page shows live nodes? http://localhost:50070/

Start all Hadoop daemons using command $ bin/start-all.sh .

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the Hadoop demons. This needs to be done in psuedo-dist mode unlike the standalone mode. You start them using something like:

`$bin\start-all.sh`

Documentation for the steps required can be found [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.18.3/quickstart.html#PseudoDistributed).

Did you follow all these steps? Can you browse the NameNode and JobTracker web interfaces?

Comment: That is the example I am trying to run. I can browse the Namenode and JobTracker, the core-site.xml file is there.
The logs look good when I start the daemons. Its only after './bin/hadooop -put conf input' that the exceptions occur.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using preconfigured virtual machine? http://www.cloudera.com/developers/downloads/virtual-machine/ I think this is probably the best way to start learning hadoop, and those problems should not happened there.

Comment: Could you tell me whether I can run Hadoop in fully distributed mode using Cloudera's VM ? Each VM will run on a different computer. As I cannot install Linux on the machines I work on :(

Comment: If you want to run Cloudera's VM on different computers you'll have some problems (related to networking). But for testing, running 2 or 3 VM on a single PC would work.